# Long and small equals sign

Tags: symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

I am looking for a large equals sign and a small equal sign.

If we use `\textdblhyphen` we get a small equals signs, but how can I simply "shrink" the usual = in LaTeX and "extend" the usual = just like the picture below?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use leaders, with some care when the required length is small.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shorteq}{\mathrel{\mkern0.2mu\mathpalette\shorteq@\relax\mkern0.2mu}}
\newcommand{\shorteq@}[2]{\scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\m@th#1=$}}

\newcommand{\longeq}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\longeq@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\longeq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \ifdim#2<\wd\z@
    \resizebox{#2}{\height}{\box\z@}%
  \else
    \ifdim#2<3\wd\z@
      \hbox to #2{$\m@th#1=\hss=\hss=\hss=$}%
    \else
      \hbox to #2{$\m@th#1=\cleaders\hbox to 0.2\wd\z@{\hss$#1=$\hss}\hfil=$}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\shorteq B$ $\scriptstyle A\shorteq B$

$A\longeq{2em}B$ $\scriptstyle A\longeq{1.6em}B$
\sbox0{$\longeq{12pt}$}\the\wd0

$A\longeq{2pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{4pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{6pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{8pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{10pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{12pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{14pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{16pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{18pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{20pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{22pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{24pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{26pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{28pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{30pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{32pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{34pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{36pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{38pt}B$\par
$A\longeq{40pt}B$\par

\end{document}
```

In case of length reduction, the ends are less curved, with Computer Modern fonts that have rounded caps.

`\shorteq` reduces the width by half; `\longeq` requires a length.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can try merging two equal signs:

```tex
$A=\joinrel=B$
```

[image: joinrel equals]

Or you can use leaders to extend this:

```tex
\def\varequals#1{\mathrel{\leaders\hbox to3pt{$=$\hss}\hskip#1=}}
$A\varequals{10pt}B$
```

[image: leaders varequals]

The use of this macro is `\varequals{dimen}` where `dimen` corresponds roughly to how much extra width you'd like your equal sign to have.

But neither of these allow you to shorten the equals sign. One solution to this that I can think of uses my package [pdfMsym](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfmsym). This solution also doesn't have the drawback of the `\leaders` solution where the center may be more bold than the edges of the long equals sign.

```tex
% In your preamble
\input pdfmsym
\pdfmsymsetscalefactor{10} % Change 10 to be the font size you're using

\makeatletter
\def\varequals#1{\@Arrow@type\@Linecap\@Linecap{#1}{1}}
\makeatother

$A\varequals{10pt}B$

$A\varequals{3pt}B$
```

[image: pdfmsym varequals]

`\@Arrow@type` creates a double stroked arrow and its parameters are, in order: its left and right lineheads, its length (this is relative to the current math style), and the height difference between the strokes. `\@Linecap` is simply a double stroked rounded line cap, whose height difference is 1.

The `\@Arrow@type` macro is not documented (but it should be).